# Remove df rows if based on some condition in column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a data frame which has 2 columns datetime and value as shown below.

```
     Datetime                 Value
==============================================
10-03-2023 00:00:00.000       10
10-03-2023 01:00:00.000       20
10-03-2023 04:00:00.000       50
```

So to impute the missing entries, I am creating index value for each hour and imputing it with **0** with the below code,

```
today = datetime.now(timezone("Asia/Kolkata")).replace(tzinfo=None).replace(microsecond=0, second=0, minute=0)
today = today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
start_date = pd.to_datetime("10-03-2023 00:00:00", format='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
start_date = start_date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
idx = pd.date_range(start_date, today, freq='H')

# imputing missing data and assigning value as 0
df = df.set_index('Datetime')
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
df = df.reset_index()
```

The above give the below data frame till **10-03-2023 05:00:00.000**

```
     Datetime                 Value
==============================================
10-03-2023 00:00:00.000       10
10-03-2023 01:00:00.000       20
10-03-2023 02:00:00.000       0
10-03-2023 03:00:00.000       0
10-03-2023 04:00:00.000       50
10-03-2023 05:00:00.000       0
```

My question is, is there a way to restrict the last entry if it contains values as **0** not value when there is values apart from 0 and also it should not do anything to entries which has value as 0 but not as the last entry.

So if the latest entry in my df is 0, it should only get removed from df.

**Edit:**
So basically my output should be like below It should not have the **05** entry as that is the last entry and its value is 0 and every hour values at which has **0** at the end.

If incase an entry which has a value greater than 0 at **6** then my DF should have all entries till 6th hour with 5th hr value as 0

```
     Datetime                 Value
==============================================
10-03-2023 00:00:00.000       10
10-03-2023 01:00:00.000       20
10-03-2023 02:00:00.000       0
10-03-2023 03:00:00.000       0
10-03-2023 04:00:00.000       50
```

Thanks,

Comment: `out = df.set_index('Datetime').reindex(idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()`

Comment: If you want to avoid filling with zeros, use the latest date as upper bound in `pd.date_range`

Comment: Just in case it helps someone: If all you want to do is remove the last row if the "Value" value is 0, you could use `if df.at[df.index[-1], 'Value'] == 0:
    df = df.drop(df.index[-1])`

Comment: @mozway, thank you for replying. I think my code is exactly the same as your answer. I just wanted to know how to remove the last entry which has a value 0. because at times, some entries will stop at different time and i don't want to have their values as 0 until i get a value for them

Comment: @SM079 Have you tried using `idx = pd.date_range(df['Datetime'].min(), df['Datetime'].max(), freq='H')` As I hinted in my second comment? If this is not what you want can you please clarify?

Comment: @Rainman, thanks for replying. The issue i have with your suggestion is that, if i run this script every hour and didnt got value for last 3 or 4 hrs, still it will remove last one entry right, where as i want to remove all last entries which are 0

Comment: "*i want to remove all last entries which are 0*" -> better not generate them in the first place ;)

Comment: Since i am crating the idx separately i am generating till last hour using the code i posted above.. can u explain me how to restrict them if possible

Comment: I just did above: `idx = pd.date_range(df['Datetime'].min(), df['Datetime'].max(), freq='H')`

Comment: That fixed my problem. thanks a lot @mozway